# FCM of same firebase project into two different android projects

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, real-time

I've two android projects connected to same firebase account, when I'm getting the FCM token from firebase for both the application I'm storing it in shared preference and sending a message from one app to another. Once I stored token I'm fetching the same token and sending message. Thing is I'm able to send message but in the other app I'm not receiving the message. Can anyone tell me if my logic is correct or what can I do to achieve this. Thanks

I am storing the FCM token in shared preference and while sending message I'm fetching it from shared preference. Will this work or what should I?

Comment: I tried to answer below, but honestly... it's not really clear what you're actually doing. If the answer I gave does not help you solve the problem, please edit your question to clarify the problem, preferably by providing the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but definitely also by following the guidance in [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: One application is for users and one is for service provider both of them will connect with either audio call or video for this I am storing their FCm token in MongoDB and showing ones profile to the other once they click on connect button I'll pass their FCm token one is sender other is reciever. I'm fetching token from MongoDB properly also in getting success response while sending message request but in the receiver side I'm not getting and notification or I'm trying to toast a successful message. But no response message I'm getting in the receivers side.

Comment: Nothing in that description sounds like it isn't possible - so the problem is more likely in your implementation of it. A textual description of that isn't the most effective way for us to help you though. Please read the guidance on [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and *edit* your question by clicking the link under it to add the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

Each FCM token is specific to a single app installation on a single device. So if you have two app descriptors in a Firebase project, each of those apps will have their own token. If you want to target a specific one of the apps, you should send the notification to that app's FCM token.